# How to use DATE_FORMAT for Mongodate in Cakephp with Mongodb?

Tags: php, mysql, mongodb, cakephp

Hi i am using MongoDB as database in my cakephp application. and i am using [this](https://github.com/ichikaway/cakephp-mongodb) plugin for it. i want to search record(document) from my user collection. i am using this snippet

```
$userDetails = $this->User->find('all',array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'userId' => 18
    )
));
```

it's working for me.

Now i wants to fetch the record by date like all user who was `created in January Month of 2016.` so for that i have to use similar to DATE_FORMAT function of MySQL and it might something like

```
$month = date('m');
$userDetails = $this->User->find('all',array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'userId' => 18,
        'DATE_FORMAT(User.created_at,"%m") =' => $month
    ),
    'fields' => array()
));
```

but how to use this type of Functionality with mongoDB can any one help me please?

thanks.

Comment: Why not `MONTH(User.created_at) =' => $month`?

Comment: it gives me blank array,
and query display to me is `db.users.find( {"rider_id":"56acb9e4d5e102c00b00002c","MONTH(User.created_at,\"%m\") $eq":"01"}, [] ).sort( [] ).limit( 0 ).skip( 0 ).hint( [] )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this :**

```
var start = new Date(2016, 01, 01);
var end = new Date(2016, 01, 31);

db.User.find({userId: 18, created_at: {$gte: start, $lt: end}});
```

Source : [here](http://mghtb.com/mongodbmongoose-date-queries/)

Comment: Thanks Monty, but it's better if i can use month directly, because in this snippet i have to find out upper and lower bound of day for month manually.

Comment: you can make it dynamic, you just have to confirm month and year, using php you can do it

Comment: @DrHadia you can also vote me if my answer is near to your answer